# PHP: Adicionar novo elemento a um array criado a partir de um objeto

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo

Olá, tenho a seguinte classe em `models/cliente.php`:

```php
<?php
class Cliente {
    public $id;
    public $nome;
    ...

    public function __construct($id, $nome, ...) {
        $this->id   = $id;
        $this->nome = $nome;
        ...
    }

    public static function all() {
        $list = [];
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $req = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clientes");
        foreach($req->fetchAll() as $cliente) {
            $list[] = new Cliente($cliente['cliente_id'], $cliente['cliente_nome'], ...);
        }
        return $list;
    }

    ...
}
?>
```

E gostaria de saber **como adicionar um novo elemento a `$list[]`**, que será obtido a partir da consulta SQL modificada como abaixo:

```php
...

$req = $db->query("SELECT clientes.*, shoppings.shopping_nome FROM clientes, shoppings WHERE clientes.shopping_id = shoppings.shopping_id");

...
```

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```php
...

$list[] = new Cliente($cliente['cliente_id'], ...);
$list[] = $cliente['shopping_nome'];

...
```

Porém não funcionou.

Agradeço desde já.

---

`controllers/clientes_controller.php`:

```php
<?php
class ClientesController {
    public function show() {
        $clientes = Cliente::all();
    }

    ...
}
```

`views/clientes/show.php`:

```php
<?php
foreach ($clientes as $cliente) {
    echo $cliente->id;
    echo $cliente->nome;
    ...
    echo $cliente->shopping_nome; // Poderia usar assim?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você não quer adicionar uma propriedade chamada `shopping_nome` em sua classe `Cliente`, certo?

Então você pode adicionar uma variável chamada `$key` no loop para obter o índice da iteração.

```
public static function all()
{
    $list = [];
    $db = Db::getInstance();
    $req = $db->query("SELECT clientes.*, shoppings.shopping_nome FROM clientes, shoppings WHERE clientes.shopping_id = shoppings.shopping_id");
    foreach($req->fetchAll() as $key => $cliente) {
        $list[$key] = new Cliente($cliente['cliente_id'], $cliente['cliente_nome'], ...);
        $list[$key]->shopping_nome = $cliente['shopping_nome'];
    }

    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria fazer. Solução tão simples. Valeu mesmo, cara!

Comment: Dê nada! Fico feliz em ajudá-lo.